# Help needed : Code coverage is 37 %. wants to improve

Tags: unit-test, class, code-coverage

[image]

class :

```
public class SendEmailWithAttachmentsController {

    final Opportunity oppty;
    public String selectedTemplateId { get;set; }
    Quote__c quote = new Quote__c();
    List<Attachment> attList = new List<Attachment>();

    public SendEmailWithAttachmentsController(ApexPages.StandardController stdController) {
        this.oppty = (Opportunity)stdController.getRecord();

        List<Quote__c> opptyQuoteList = [Select id,Name,Opportunity__r.Account.Email__c, Opportunity__r.AccountId 
                                                    FROM Quote__c 
                                                    where Opportunity__c =:oppty.Id];
        if(!opptyQuoteList.isEmpty()){
            quote = opptyQuoteList[0];
        }
    }

    public List<SelectOption> getEmailTemplateOptions() {
        List<SelectOption> options = new List<SelectOption>();
        for (EmailTemplate template : [Select Id,Name FROM EmailTemplate]) {

            options.add(new SelectOption(template.Id, template.Name));
        }
        return options;
    }

    public PageReference sendEmail() {
        try{

            // Define the email
            Messaging.SingleEmailMessage email = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage(); 

            List<Messaging.Emailfileattachment> fileAttachments = new List<Messaging.Emailfileattachment>();

            // Reference the attachment page and pass in the account ID
            PageReference quotePdf = Page.PrintQuote;
            quotePdf.getParameters().put('id', quote.Id);
            quotePdf.setRedirect(true);

            // Take the PDF content
            Blob b = quotePdf.getContent();

            // Create the email attachment
            Messaging.EmailFileAttachment efa = new Messaging.EmailFileAttachment();
            efa.setFileName( quote.Name + '.pdf');
            efa.setBody(b);
            fileAttachments.add(efa);

            Attachment att = new Attachment();
            att.body = b;
            att.Name = quote.Name + '.pdf';
            attList.add(att);

            for (Attachment a : [select Name, Body, BodyLength from Attachment where ParentId = :oppty.Id]) {
                // Add to attachment file list
                Messaging.Emailfileattachment opptyAttach = new Messaging.Emailfileattachment();
                opptyAttach.setFileName(a.Name);
                opptyAttach.setBody(a.Body);
                fileAttachments.add(opptyAttach);

                Attachment att1 = new Attachment();
                att1.body = a.Body;
                att1.Name = a.Name;
                attList.add(att1);
            }
            email.setFileAttachments(fileAttachments);

            //create dummy contact
            contact con = new contact();
            con.lastname = 'test con';
            con.Email = 'dummy@organization.com';
            con.accountid = quote.Opportunity__r.AccountId;
            insert con;

            email.setTemplateId( selectedTemplateId );
            email.setWhatId(oppty.id);
            email.setTargetObjectId(con.id);
            email.setToAddresses(new List<String>{quote.Opportunity__r.Account.Email__c});
            // Sends the email
            Messaging.SendEmailResult [] r = Messaging.sendEmail(new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[] {email});
            if (r.get(0).isSuccess()) {
                //delete con;

                Task conTask = [Select Id, Subject, Description, Status, WhatId FROM Task WHERE WhoId =: con.Id];
                conTask.WhoId = null;
                update conTask;

                if(!attList.isEmpty()){
                    for(Attachment attOne : attList){
                        attOne.ParentId = conTask.Id;
                    }

                    insert attList;
                }
                delete con;
            }

        } catch(Exception ex){
            system.debug('@@ex : '+ ex.getMessage());
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Test Class :

```
@isTest(SeeAllData=true)
public class SendEmailWithAttachmentsControllerTest{

   static testMethod void MyTest(){
         Account a = new Account();
        a.Name = 'test';
        a.Email__c = 'test@test.com';
        a.CurrencyIsoCode = 'EUR';
        a.Phone = '789642';
        a.BillingCity= 'bhuj';
        a.BillingPostalCode = '370001';
        a.BillingCountry = 'india';
        a.BillingLatitude = 57.5 ;
        a.BillingLongitude = 67.7;
        a.BillingState = 'Gujarat';
        a.BillingStreet = 'Main';
        insert a;

        Opportunity opp = new Opportunity();
        opp.Name = 'Test Opportunity';
        opp.StageName = 'Stage 0';
        opp.CloseDate = system.today().addDays(10);
        opp.Accountid = a.id;
        opp.CurrencyIsoCode = 'GBP';
        insert opp;

        Contact con = new Contact ();
        con.firstName = 'test';
        con.lastName = 'User';
        con.AccountId = a.id;
        con.Email = 'dummy@organization.com';
        con.CurrencyIsoCode = 'GBP';
        insert con;

        Quote__c quote = new Quote__c();
        quote.CurrencyIsoCode = 'GBP';
        quote.Opportunity__c = opp.Id;
        insert quote;


        Blob b = Blob.valueOf('Test Data');  


        Messaging.EmailFileAttachment efa = new Messaging.EmailFileAttachment();
        efa.setFileName( quote.Name + '.pdf');
        efa.setBody(b); 

        Attachment attachment = new Attachment();  
        attachment.ParentId = opp.id;  
        attachment.Name = 'Test Attachment for Parent';  
        attachment.Body = b;  
        insert(attachment);

        Task task = new Task();
        task.Customer_Name__c = a.id;
        task.Total_Amount__c = 12000;
        task.WhatId = opp.id;
        task.Opportunity__c = opp.id;
        task.ActivityDate = system.today();
        task.Subject = 'Invoice ';
        task.CurrencyIsoCode = 'GBP';
        task.Status = 'Completed';
        task.Priority ='Normal';
        insert task;

        Blob b1; 
        try{ 
            b1 = page.SendEmailWithAttachments.getContent(); 
        }catch(VisualforceException e){
            b1 = Blob.valueOf('BLob when occur error');
        }

        Apexpages.currentPage().getParameters().put('id',quote.Id);
        ApexPages.StandardController sc = new ApexPages.StandardController(opp);
        SendEmailWithAttachmentsController swa = new SendEmailWithAttachmentsController(sc);
        test.startTest();
        swa.getEmailTemplateOptions();
        test.stopTest();
        swa.sendEmail();
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to show us what is happening before the line 44 in your screenshot so we would know why the highlighted code is not executed by your test method.

Comment: i have updated my question with whole class

Answer (score 0):

You are probably getting an exception somewhere before the code line 44 in your `sendEmail` method and it's causing your test execution to jump to `catch` block and not go through the rest of the method.

In your `catch` block you are writing an output with `system.debug('@@ex : '+ ex.getMessage());` which means that once you run your test it should probably generate a new log.

In your `developer console`, find your `logs` tab (at the bottom of the screen) and double click the most recent log. Then when your `Execution Log` window opens select the `Debug Only` checkbox at the bottom of that window and you should be able to see what is the exception that your test has thrown. Next you'll have to fix either your test or your `sendEmail` method in order to solve that problem and get more coverage.

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: No. i am not getting the coverage yet

Comment: Did you managed to find out what exception is being thrown?